# Fastest way to open all files in a directory with multiple file extensions on commandline

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, wildcards

If I want to open all `mp4` files in a directory, I can simply do something like `totem *.mp4`. But how can I open all `mp4` and all `flv` files in that directory with one command. I.e. I want to do something like this `totem (*.mp4 OR *.flv)`. What's the easiest way to do this? Perhaps it helps that I am using `zsh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call

```
totem *.mp4 *.flv
```

Too easy, isn't it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Or in a single pattern (with `extended_glob`):

```
totem *.(mp4|flv)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or slightly more compact:

```
totem *.{mp4,flv}
```

Comment: +1 This works on `bash` as well.